# Python: r2py cannot load library R/lib/libR.dylib

Tags: python, r

I have installed `r2py` via `pip` on a Mac OS.

```
python3 -m pip install rpy2
```

If I try to call it I get an error

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R'
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

OSError: cannot load library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/lib/libR.dylib': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/lib/libR.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/lib/libR.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
```